# How to add composite primary key to table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, foreign-keys, primary-key

```
create table d(id numeric(1), code varchar(2))
```

After I create the above table how can I add a composite primary key on both fields and also a foreign key?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In Oracle, you could do this:

```
create table D (
  ID numeric(1),
  CODE varchar(2),
  constraint PK_D primary key (ID, CODE)
);
```

Comment: create table tr(id numeric(1),bin varchar(10))
alter table tr add constraint pk_id  primary key (id, bin)


its not worked why

Comment: @simonn: just curious, cannot check right now, but is the NOT NULL for the columns implicit, or do you need to add them to the column definitions?

Answer (score 33):

`alter table d add constraint pkc_Name primary key (id, code)`

should do it.  There's lots of options to a basic primary key/index depending on what DB your working with.

Comment: create table tr(id numeric(1),bin varchar(10))
alter table tr add constraint pk_id  primary key (id, bin)


its not worked

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to create the table first and then add the keys in subsequent steps. You can add both primary key and foreign key while creating the table:

This example assumes the existence of a table (`Codes`) that we would want to reference with our foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE d (
id [numeric](1),
code [varchar](2),
PRIMARY KEY (id, code),
CONSTRAINT fk_d_codes FOREIGN KEY (code) REFERENCES Codes (code)
)
```

If you don't have a table that we can reference, add one like this so that the example will work:

```
CREATE TABLE Codes (
    Code [varchar](2) PRIMARY KEY   
    )
```

**NOTE:** you must have a table to reference before creating the foreign key.

Answer (score 6):

The `ALTER TABLE` statement presented by Chris should work, but first you need to declare the columns `NOT NULL`. All parts of a primary key need to be `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 4):

If using Sql Server Management Studio Designer just select both rows (Shift+Click) and Set Primary Key.

[image]

Comment: im pretty sure that deletes the other key constraints